# font-face working in chrome but not in firefox and ie

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, font-face

I think the title already says what my problem is.

Here's my code, I hope you can tell what I'm doing wrong:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Deer';
  src: url('fonts/Deer.eot') format('embedded-opentype');
  src: url('fonts/Deer.woff') format('woff'),
       url('fonts/Deer.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

IE is downloading the ttf and woff files but not the eot, and firefox is downloading none of them...

Comment: it should work... maybe your woff-file is broken or at the wrong place? see a google font example: http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans or maybe you have noscript installed? noscript blocks google fonts, just look at the noscript icon. _edit_ you got the wrong syntax i think

Comment: if I remove everything except the woff file, it's still working in chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Deer';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  src: url('fonts/Deer.woff') format('woff'),
       url('fonts/Deer.eot') format('eot'),
       url('fonts/Deer.ttf') format('ttf');
}
```

i dont think more than 1 `src`-argument is allowed in @font-face.

Comment: try again, i changed the format descriptors and the font order

Comment: where exactly did you get the "Deer.woff" file from? i can only find Deer.ttf on dafont.com. did you convert it yourself?

Comment: yes I converted it (with http://www.font2web.com/) but the woff file seems to work because if I remove the other ones and try it in chrome, it's still working

Comment: i converted with onlinefontconverter.com just now and it is working in firefox with above code. look here: http://blim-dev.com/